# PHPmailer not sending emails if I include a link inside the mail body

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

session_start();
include '../connection.php';

// echo dirname(__FILE__);
// echo dirname(__DIR__).'/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

include dirname(__DIR__) . '/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
// include 'https://legaldiary.000webhostapp.com/android/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
// include dirname(__FILE__).'../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
// // require 'path/to/your/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
include dirname(__DIR__) . '/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
include dirname(__DIR__) . '/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
// require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function checkPasswordStrength($password)
{
    if (preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d).{8,}$/', $password)) {
        return 'very_strong';
    } elseif (preg_match('/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}$/', $password)) {
        return 'strong';
    } elseif (strlen($password) >= 8) {
        return 'weak';
    } else {
        return 'very_weak';
    }
}

function generateVerificationToken()
{
    return bin2hex(random_bytes(32));  // Use a secure method to generate a random token
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (
        isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['username'])
        && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['confirmPassword']) || true
    ) {
        // Get data from the POST request
        // $name = $_POST['name'];
        // $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        // $email = $_POST['email'];
        // $username = $_POST['username'];
        // $password = $_POST['password'];
        // $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];

        $name = 'Ram';
        $phone = '9876542310';
        $email = 'yashigoyal02@gmail.com';
        $username = 'Ram@123';
        $password = 'Admin@123';
        $confirmPassword = 'Admin@123';
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Invalid email format."));
            die();
            // exit;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^\d{10}$/', $phone)) {
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Invalid phone number format. It should have exactly 10 digits."));
            die(); // Terminate script execution
        }


        $conn = connectToDatabase();

        // Check if email or phone number already exists
        $checkEmailQuery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE email = '$email'";
        $checkPhoneQuery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE phn = '$phone'";

        $resultEmail = executeQuery($conn, $checkEmailQuery);
        $resultPhone = executeQuery($conn, $checkPhoneQuery);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($resultEmail) > 0) {
            // Email is already used
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Email is already registered."));
        } elseif (mysqli_num_rows($resultPhone) > 0) {
            // Phone number is already used
            echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Phone number is already registered."));
        } else {
            if ($password != $confirmPassword) {
                echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Both the passwords do not match."));
                die();
            }

            $passStrength = checkPasswordStrength($password);
            // Check if the password is weak or very weak
            if ($passStrength === 'weak' || $passStrength === 'very_weak') {
                echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Password is too weak. Choose a stronger password.
                \nThe password should contain at least 1 capital letter, 1 small letter, 1 digit and 1 special character.
                \nThe minimum length of the password should be 8.
                "));
                die();
            }

            // Check if username already exists
            $checkUsernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM userdetails WHERE username = '$username'";
            $resultUsername = executeQuery($conn, $checkUsernameQuery);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($resultUsername) > 0) {
                // Username is already taken
                echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Username is already taken."));
            } else {
                // Insert the new user record
                $verificationToken = generateVerificationToken();
                $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO userdetails (name, phn, username, password, email, token) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$username', '$password', '$email', '$verificationToken')";
               
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $insertQuery)) {
                // if (true) {
                    $userId = mysqli_insert_id($conn);


                    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

                    try {
                        // Server settings
                        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
                        $mail->isSMTP();
                        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify your SMTP server
                        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
                        $mail->Username   = '***';        // SMTP username
                        $mail->Password   = '***';        // SMTP password
                        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                   // Enable TLS encryption
                        $mail->Port       = 587;                     // TCP port to connect to

                        $mail->SMTPOptions = array('ssl' => array('verify_peer'       => false,
                                          'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                                          'allow_self_signed' => true));
                        // Recipients
                        $mail->setFrom('noreply@advoconnect.com', 'Team AdvoConnect');
                        $mail->addAddress($email);

                        // Content
                        $mail->isHTML(true);
                        $mail->Subject = 'Email Verification';
                        $mail->Body    = 'Click the link to verify your email: <a href="https://legaldiary.000webhostapp.com/android/signup/verify.php?token=' . $verificationToken . '">Verify Email</a>';
               
                        // 'Hii';
                    
                        $mail->send();

                        echo json_encode(array("status" => "success", "message" => "Registration successful. Check your email for verification."));
                    } 
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Error in sending email: " . $e));
                    }
                } else {
                    // Error in registration
                    echo json_encode(array("status" => "error", "message" => "Error in registration."));
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Return error if username or email and password are not set
        echo json_encode(["error" => "All the fields are required."]);
    }
} else {
    // Return error if the request method is not POST
    echo json_encode(["error" => "Invalid request method. Use POST."]);
}



// Close the database connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

This is the code that I am using for signup in my application.
I am using phpmailer to send verification email to the entered mail id.

Now, if i just put Hii in the $mail->body, the email gets sent successfully.

But if I use the click here to verify text and the link in the mail body, I still see the registration successful message and the mail is in the outbox of the username email

But it does not get recieved in the inbox of the $email.

I have read various articles on this and tried a lot of things but nothing works.

Please help.

---

Comment: Checked your spam/junk folder?

Comment: Don't store plain text passwords

Comment: @brombeer i did check the spam folder but its not there

Comment: where should i not store plain passwords?


ohh i understood you meant in the database?

Comment: if yes, please suggest me how to encrypt and store them and then how to verify password when a user logs in

Comment: PHP has [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: I would not be all too surprised, if a cheap hosting service like `000webhostapp.com` was on plenty of block lists already. Try and send that same link, but with a different domain part in the URL - something that doesn't smell like "probably spam, when it is hosted on _that_ service" three miles against the wind already. If that works, then you know that you should probably change your hosting to something a bit "better."

Comment: yess I tried with some other link and that works perfectly fine. 
Thanks for the insight.